# IGListkit networking responsibility

Tags: ios, iglistkit

Using IGListkit and a bit confused on responsibilities for grabbing data.

dummy example - let's say I'm working with vehicle categories and I want to have a section controller essentially do things with car brands for a category.

My view controller has a concept of brands and the sections controllers will display a list of models for those car brands:

- Honda

  - Civic
  - Pilot
  - Accord

In the application, I need to make a network call to get the individual models.

Would this responsibility be of the view controller, essentially calling the api multiple times, getting all models for a brand, building models and then passing them to the section controller?

Or would the view controller simply pass the brand (Honda) to the section controller and then the section controller is responsible for making the network call and grabbing all it's brands and reloading itself?

Comment: personally i would make an MVVM architecture that each view model to be responsible for fetching data. But if this is the case, you could simply make your Models that way so they can have a brandName as a String and an array of carModels which is another model that has name etc. in this way you can have a single array passed in the 1st viewcontroller and then inside the sectioncontroller you have access at each array of each brand.

Answer (score 0):

IGListKit deals with arrays of objects to create necessary sections for them. I wouldn't put all the networking inside a UIViewController class but instead - create a `ListAdapterDataSource` subclass for your particular task which would do 3 different networking requests.

In the callback for each of them you'd append the results to a `ListDiffable` array:

```
var users: [ListDiffable] = [] {
    didSet {
        update()
    }
}

private func update() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.adapter.performUpdates(animated: true, completion: { _ in
            self?.loading = false
        })
    }
}
```

Calling the `performUpdates` this way ensures IGListKit uses it's smart diffing algorithm to only change/add cells that are recently added leaving already displayed intact and not affecting the performance. You can set different classes for sections/cells in the `func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController` method of `ListAdapterDataSource` protocol